# Select Distinct from DataTable using Linq and C#

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, distinct

I need to select distinct records from a data table using linq and C# and I can't seem to get the syntax correct.  I have the following code, which returns all the rows in a data table, how do I just return DISTINCT rows?

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
var q = from dr in dt.AsEnumerable() select dr;
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to use [DataRowComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowcomparer.aspx)

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> distinctRows = 
    dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
```

More info on comparing data rows using linq to dataset can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386998.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

We could have:

```
var q = (from dr in dt.AsEnumerable() select dr).Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
```

But really, the `from x in ... select x` is redundant, so we can have:

```
var q = dt.AsEnumerable().Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
```

But all `AsEnumerable()` will do most of the time, is either nothing (if it's already as such) or potentially slow things up (if distinct could be processed better elsewhere), so it's normally better to do:

```
var q = dt.Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default);
```

Though there are cases where the former beats the latter.

Comment: this is going to compare the rows by reference, not based on the field values

Comment: @vc74 Right you are, I mentioned the override but didn't even notice that this was a case where it must be used, oops.

Comment: No worries, btw, did you mean dt.ROWS.Distinct(DataRowComparer.Default) ?

Comment: @vc74 LOL. Yes, yes I did. I think I'm going to leave it at this point. Your comment fixes the flaw and too many fixes reaches a point bordering on dishonesty.

Comment: Reads like a very honest sentence to me :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(from dr in dt.AsEnumerable() select dr).Distinct();
```

Comment: This made sense to me too, what reference am I missing?  I get the following error:   
Error 1 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' does not contain a definition for 'Distinct' and no extension method 'Distinct' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<System.Data.DataRow>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)