# How can I maintain type when using LINQ .Select in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to return a Distinct set of results that are first trimmed using Substring, but when I call "Select" it converts it to an anonymous type. I can't seem to get this to maintain the type "List". I only need to return the fields specified in the Select method.

```
public List<Facility> GetFacilities() {
    var facilities = new List<Facility>(); 
    facilities = _facilityRepository.GetAll().ToList();
    var facReturnList = 
        facilities.Where(x => x.Fac_Name = "Something")
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Fac_Name).ToList();

    var facReturnList2 = 
        facReturnList.Select(x => 
            new { ID = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 6), 
                  Fac_Name = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 3) })
            .Distinct().ToList();
    return facReturnList2;
}
```

I tried adding `List<Facility>` after `new`, but it says those properties (`ID` and `Fac_Name`) aren't defined in Facility.

Comment: You'd probably be better of using a model for Facility instead of returning the entity itself. Furthermore, you can often trim down the query by not using `.ToList()` in between queries. The first two linq queries probably do not need a call to `ToList`, unless the distinct you use is not convertable to sql. (Are we talking about a datacontext btw?)

Comment: @Silvermind,  think you are right on both accounts, but I am new to this technology, thus I cannot say for sure that this is a "datacontext"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to initialize new `Facility` instances with your results?

```
var facReturnList2 = facReturnList.Select(x => new Facility { ID =   // ...
                                                   ^ concrete type initializer
```

**Response to edit**: Inside the `Select` operator, you need to specify the type of the *elements* that you want to initialize, not their list. Your prior code seems to indicate that `Fac_Name` *is* defined in `Facility`, but it obviously wouldn't be defined in `List<Facility>`.

Comment: This is what I was missing. I just needed to cast it as a Facility not a List<Facility>. Thanks!

Comment: you need to *construct* it as a Facility, not cast it

Comment: @fguchelaar, I figured the terminology wasn't correct. I'll be sure to look that up.

Comment: @JamesRLamar: They're called [object initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx). You may follow the preceding link to their MSDN article.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting an anonymous type because you are creating it.

```
.Select(x => new {
```

If you do not want that, do not do that.

If an existing type already has the name and the precise properties you need, use that. If no type has what you need, *create one.* Then you can return a proper list or enumerable of that type.

```
.Select(x => new YourDefinedType {
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you really want is a `DistinctBy` method.  You want to specify some means of indicating that an object is distinct, but you don't want the result to be a collection of that selection, you want the end result to be the starting object.  LINQ has no `DistinctBy` built in, but implementing one is easy enough:

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    HashSet<TKey> knownKeys = new HashSet<TKey>(comparer);
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (knownKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

Using that your code can now become:

```
public List<Facility> GetFacilities()
{
    return _facilityRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(x => x.Fac_Name == "Something")
        .DistinctBy(x => new
        {
            ID = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 6),
            Fac_Name = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 3)
        })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Fac_Name)
        .ToList();
}
```

In the event that you have an `IQueryable` as opposed to an in memory data set, you can use `GroupBy` to get the same behavior.  In Linq-to-objects using `GroupBy` would be a lot less efficient, but for a query provider it will not be as the database is capable of optimizing this.

```
public List<Facility> GetFacilities()
{
    return _facilityRepository.GetAll()
        .Where(x => x.Fac_Name == "Something")
        .OrderBy(x => x.Fac_Name)
        .GroupBy(x => new
        {
            ID = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 6),
            Fac_Name = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 3)
        })
        .Select(group => group.First())
        .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I am still not getting distinct results yet and using your code "DistinctBy" is not a recognized extension method. I will create another question regarding this issue here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15301068/how-to-get-a-distinct-result-using-linq-and-c-sharp-using-method-syntax . I think your answer and this one may be on the right track, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853390/select-distinct-from-datatable-using-linq-and-c-sharp

Comment: @JamesRLamar I provided the definition of the extension method in this post.  As I said, it doesn't exist in LINQ itself.

Comment: I got ya. I added the static class for it like you suggested. There are couple of other things in the background I do to get the repository, so I'm guessing that's where the conflict may be. I greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is instructing linq to return an anonymous type:

```
.Select(x => new { ID = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 6), Fac_Name = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 3) }
```

You need to create a class for your results

```
public class Result{
    public string ID { get;set; }
    public string Fac_Name { get; set; }
}

//Then do

.Select(x => new Result { ID = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 6), Fac_Name = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 3) }
```

This ensures you are only returning the information you need