# How to get a Distinct result using LINQ and C# using method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

The following code still does not return a DISTINCT result set. The equivalent SQL I am trying to accomplish is `SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(Fac_Name, 6) AS ID, LEFT(Fac_Name, 3) AS Fac_Name`

```
 public List<Facility> GetFacilities() {
        var facilities = new List<Facility>(); 
        facilities = _facilityRepository.GetAll().ToList();
        var facReturnList = 
            facilities.Where(x => x.Fac_Name = "Something")
                      .OrderBy(x => x.Fac_Name).ToList();

        var facReturnList2 = 
            facReturnList.Select(x => 
                new Facility { ID = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 6), 
                      Fac_Name = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 3) })
                .Distinct().ToList();
        return facReturnList2;
    }
```

Comment: James when you debug the code do the following `var` variables yield when you hover over each one ..? are you getting duplicates ? any data at all ..etc...?

Comment: You have already posted this exact question less than half an hour ago, and got a number of answers.  You should not re-post the same question just because you aren't satisfied with existing answers.  You also shouldn't mark an answer as "the answer" if it doesn't solve your problem.

Comment: @Servy, the previous question was related specifically to the anonymous type I was getting and how to get it to return the type I needed. This certainly is related to the same set of code, but specifically to how to get Distinct results. I didn't want to try and answer two problems with one question, but maybe I should have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you have is that you're creating distinct reference values (which will return different hashcodes), even if the properties inside each reference are equal, the actual references themselves are distinct.

```
// fac1 and fac2 are the same reference, fac3 is a different reference.
var fac1 = new Facility { ID = "0", Fac_Name = "Hello" };
var fac2 = fac1;
var fac3 = new Facility { ID = "0", Fac_Name = "Hello" };

var facs = new List<Facility>() { fac1, fac2, fac3 };

foreach (var fac in facs.Distinct())
    Console.WriteLine("Id: {0} | Name: {1}", fac.ID, fac.Fac_Name);

// OUTPUT
// Id: 0 | Name: Hello (NOTE: This is the value of fac1/fac2)
// Id: 0 | Name: Hello (This is the value of fac3)
```

To solve your dilemma, you should either:

- Override the [`Object.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) and the [`Object.Equals(Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.equals.aspx) methods. Note that `Distinct()` ultimately uses the GetHashCode() to determine if something is distinct, but `Equals(Object)` and `GetHashCode()` should be overridden together.
  [Guidelines for Overloading Equals() and Operator ==](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx)

  public class Facility
  {
      public string ID { get; set; }
      public string Fac_Name { get; set; }

  ```
  // This is just a rough example.
  public override bool Equals(Object obj)
  {
      var fac = obj as Facility;
      if (fac == null) return false;

      if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, fac)) return true;

      return (this.ID == fac.ID) && (this.Fac_Name == fac.Fac_Name);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode()
  {
      var hash = 13;

      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ID))
          hash ^= ID.GetHashCode();
      if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Fac_Name))
          hash ^= Fac_Name.GetHashCode();

      return hash;
  }
  ```

  }

---

- Provide a custom [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx).

```
public class FacilityEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Facility>
{
    public bool Equals(Facility x, Facility y)
    {
        return (x.ID == y.ID) && (x.Fac_Name == y.Fac_Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Facility fac)
    {
        var hash = 13;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.ID))
            hash ^= ID.GetHashCode();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Fac_Name))
            hash ^= Fac_Name.GetHashCode();

        return hash;
    }
}

var facReturnList2 = 
        facReturnList.Select(x => 
            new Facility { ID = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 6), 
                  Fac_Name = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 3) })
            .Distinct(new FacilityEqualityComparer()).ToList();
```

---

Also, some other things to note:

1. You're naming does not follow guidelines. Don't use underscores in property names, and ID should be Id.
2. Whichever way you decide to go with, you should look into using `String.Equals(...)` and specify a StringComparison value. I just used `==` equality comparison on strings to keep the post short and readable.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that the [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) method uses the default equality comparer - which is comparing hash codes - so it will be a distinct list regardless of the properties values. Build an equality comparer for that type:

```
public class FacilityEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Facility>
{
    public bool Equals(Facility fac1, Facility fac2)
    {
        return fac1.ID.Equals(fac2.ID) && fac1.Fac_Name.Equals(fac2.Fac_Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Facility fac)
    {
        string hCode = fac.ID + fac.Fac_Name;
        return hCode.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

and then when you use it, call it like this:

```
var facReturnList2 = 
    facReturnList.Select(x => 
        new Facility { ID = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 6), 
              Fac_Name = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 3) })
        .Distinct(new FacilityEqualityComparer()).ToList();
return facReturnList2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Distinct uses the default equality comparer to check for equality. This means it's looking for reference equality, which obviously won't be there in your case.

So you'll either need to use a custom `IEqualityComparer` (see the overload for `Distinct()`, or you can replicate the functionality of `Distinct()` with a `GroupBy()` and a `First()`:

```
facReturnList.Select(x => 
                       new Facility { ID = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 6), 
                       Fac_Name = x.Fac_Name.Substring(0, 3) 
                     })
             .GroupBy(x => new{x.ID, x.Fac_Name})
             .Select(y => y.First())
             .ToList();
```

You could also Override the Equals method in your `Facility` class:

```
public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
    if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
    if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
    Facility objAsFacility = obj as Facility;
    return Equals(objAsFacility);
}

protected bool Equals(Facility other)
{
    if (other.Fac_Name == this.Fac_Name)
        return true;
    else return false;
}  

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return this.Fac_Name.GetHashCode(); 
    //Or you might even want to this:
    //return (this.ID + this.Fac_Name).GetHashCode();
}
```

I'd probably go with the overriding equality operator method.